# convert numpy array to 0 or 1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
A = np.array([[0.94366988, 0.86095311, 0.88896715, 0.93630641, 0.74075403, 0.52849619
                  , 0.03094677, 0.85707681, 0.88457925, 0.67279696, 0.26601085, 0.4823794
                  , 0.74741157, 0.78575729, 0.00978911, 0.9203284, 0.02453695, 0.84884703
                  , 0.2050248, 0.03703224, 0.92931392, 0.11930532, 0.01411064, 0.7832698
                  , 0.58188015, 0.66897565, 0.75119007, 0.01323558, 0.03402649, 0.99735115
                  , 0.21031727, 0.78123225, 0.6815842, 0.46647604, 0.66323375, 0.03424828
                  , 0.08031627, 0.76570656, 0.34760863, 0.06177743, 0.6987531, 0.4106426
                  , 0.6648871, 0.02776868, 0.93053125, 0.46395717, 0.23971605, 0.9771735
                  , 0.66202407, 0.10482388]])
```

Convert the entries of a into 0 (if activation <= 0.5) or 1 (if activation > 0.5)

```
for i in range(A.shape[1]):
if A[i]>0.5:
    Y_prediction[i] = 1
else:
    Y_prediction[i] = 0
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

And how to use vectorize this
thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing Numpy elements if condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766757/replacing-numpy-elements-if-condition-is-met)

Answer (score 70):

I think you need vectorized function [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
B = np.where(A > 0.5, 1, 0)
print (B)
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
  1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0]]
```

---

```
B = np.where(A <= 0.5, 0, 1)
print (B)
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
  1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0]]
```

But better is [holdenweb solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45648782/2901002) if need convert to `0` and `1` only.

`np.where` is better if need convert to another scalars like `5` and `10` or `a` and `b`:

```
C = np.where(A > 0.5, 5, 10)
print (C)
[[ 5  5  5  5  5  5 10  5  5  5 10 10  5  5 10  5 10  5 10 10  5 10 10  5
   5  5  5 10 10  5 10  5  5 10  5 10 10  5 10 10  5 10  5 10  5 10 10  5
   5 10]]

D = np.where(A > 0.5, 'a', 'b')
print (D)
[['a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'a' 'b' 'a'
  'b' 'b' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'a' 'b' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'a' 'b'
  'b' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'a' 'b' 'a' 'b' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'a' 'a' 'b']]
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(223)
A = np.random.rand(1,1000000)

#jez
In [64]: %timeit np.where(A > 0.5, 1, 0)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.58 ms per loop

#holdenweb
In [65]: %timeit (A > 0.5).astype(int)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.47 ms per loop

#stamaimer
In [66]: %timeit element_wise_round(A)
1 loop, best of 3: 318 ms per loop
```

Comment: Good answer. `np.where` is my goto method for this. I prefer it over broadcasting to bools and converting to int, it's just more readable imo and applicable to other scalars and datatypes as you show.

Answer (score 34):

Standard `numpy` broadcasting can be used to compare each element with a scalar value, yielding a Boolean for each element. The `ndarray.astype` method then converts the `True` values to 1 and the `False` values to zero.

```
In [16]: (A > 0.5).astype(int)
Out[16]:
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
        1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I assure you it does. Just checked with Python 3.9 and numpy 1.21.2. Not a terribly information-packed bug report, so I regret I'm unable to help further.

Comment: While checking I also checked the timing, and this method appears (on my computer!) to run about twice as fast as the most-upvoted answer. Not that speed is everything.

Comment: I've checked it both within my local Python install (also running 3.9) and [here](https://pynative.com/online-python-code-editor-to-execute-python-code/), and it didn't work on a numpy array for me.

Comment: Again, I have no information that might help me to help you solve my problem. This is like "Help. My car is broken. Tell me what I need to do to fix it." I used the numpy array given in the question. I'm sure there are a million things it wouldn't work on, but none of them will be numpy arrays of real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

```
np.random.seed(223)
A = np.random.rand(1000000)
A = [0 if i <=0.5 else 1 for i in A]
```

Comment: Thx！can you tell me how to implement use for loop?

Comment: this is a list comprehension, which is much faster than using for loops in python. You don't need to loop to get the result. @jezrael 's answer is also a good method.

Comment: @Tkanno - I cannot add your solution for timeit, because `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` :(

Comment: @jezrael that's because you've declared the array A shape (1,1000000). my method works on a flattened array, another limitation. if you flatten A you can timeit on my method.

Comment: @Tkanno - I try set input by data similar OP. But in my opinion here list comprehension is slowiest, because not vectorized. Is possible update your solution working with A? Then I can add timings too (if want)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is the dimension of A[i] in your code. 
A is initialised as matrix[1,n] (1 row and n columns - you have double [[]] brackets in np.array([[]])), so you reference of type A[i] actually means "the whole i'th row, or an array(n) in this case). 
I'm quite new to python and numpy, but to access individual cells and set each to 1 or 0 could be coded this way (of course, only if you are forced to use FOR loops here):

```
 for i in range(A.shape[1]):
 if A[0,i]>0.5:
    Y_prediction[0,i] = 1
 else:
    Y_prediction[0,i] = 0
```

But,definitely, the best solution, as others described above, is to avoid for loop.

Answer (score 1):

*this may solve your issue*

```
a=1
b=0
predict=list()
for i in A:
    if i>0.5:
        predict.append(a)
    else:
        predict.append(b)
print(predict)
```

*we first assign value a to 0 and b to 1 but you can directly use 1 and 0 on append function*
*'A' contains the list in form of probability from which we assign the new list name predict and after comparing each items in list we put value into list by using append methord*
*predict list contain your ans*

Answer (score 0):

You can make the built-in `round` function element wise use `np.vectorize`.

```
import numpy as np

element_wise_round = np.vectorize(round, otypes=[np.int])

print element_wise_round(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A1=A-0.5
A2=np.sign(A1)
```

Now you have 1 and -1. If you do not have 0 in the original array, you can convert the -1 to 0 to have only 1 and 0 array:

```
indices = A2 == -1
A2[indices] = 0
```

The result:

```
A2
```

> array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.,
> 1.,
> 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.,
> 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.,
> 1., 0.]])