# Convert NumPy array to 0 or 1 based on threshold

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array below:

```
a=np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9])
```

What I want is to convert this vector to a binary vector based on a threshold. 
take threshold=0.5 as an example, element that greater than 0.5 convert to 1, otherwise 0.
The output vector should like this:

```
a_output = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing Numpy elements if condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766757/replacing-numpy-elements-if-condition-is-met)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

#### `np.where`

```
np.where(a > 0.5, 1, 0)
# array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

---

#### Boolean basking with `astype`

```
(a > .5).astype(int)
# array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

---

#### `np.select`

```
np.select([a <= .5, a>.5], [np.zeros_like(a), np.ones_like(a)])
# array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

---

#### Special case: `np.round`

This is the best solution if your array values are floating values between 0 and 1 and your threshold is 0.5.

```
a.round()
# array([0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.])
```

Comment: Which one is fastest for working with dtype 'uint8'? The `np.select` approach returns a 'uint8' by default but looks a lot more involved.

Comment: If you wish to get a Numpy array of dtype 'bool' then `a > 0.5` will give you that.

Comment: @user3613932 I wrote this answer a while back but if I'm not mistaken you can get a bool mask with a > .5 and then call .view to change the view to uint8 which should be faster than astype... Take a look and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Based on [official documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) not sure how safe `view` is compared to `astype`. `astype` creates a new copy whereas `view` leverages the memory of the original variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `binarize` from the `sklearn.preprocessing module`.

However this will work only if you want your final values to be binary i.e. '0' or '1'. The answers provided above are great of non-binary results as well.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import binarize

a = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]).reshape(1,-1)
x = binarize(a) 
a_output = np.ravel(x)
print(a_output) 

#everything together 
a_output = np.ravel(binarize(a.reshape(1,-1), 0.5))
```