# Apply conditional function to every element of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have this function:

```
if elem < 0:
    elem = 0
else:
    elem = 1
```

I want to apply this function to every element in a NumPy array, which would be done with a `for loop` when performing this function for only the same dimensions. But in this case, I need it to work regardless of the array dimensions and shape. Would there be any way this can be achieved in Python with NumPy?

Or would there be any general way to apply any `def` to every element in a NumPy n-dimensional array?

Comment: Also: [Replacing Numpy elements if condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19766757/7851470)

Comment: Also: [Convert NumPy array to 0 or 1 based on threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46214291/7851470)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isn't it

```
arr = (arr >= 0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 5):

### [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
np.where(arr < 0, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a boolean mask to define an array of decisions. Let's work through a concrete example. You have an array of positive and negative numbers and you want to take the square root only at non-negative locations:

```
arr = np.random.normal(size=100)
```

You compute a mask like

```
mask = arr >= 0
```

The most straightforward way to apply the mask is to create an output array, and fill in the required elements:

```
result = np.empty(arr.shape)
result[mask] = np.sqrt(arr[mask])
result[~mask] = arr[~mask]
```

This is not super efficient because you have to compute the inverse of the mask and apply it multiple times. For this specific example, your can take advantage of the fact that [`np.sqrt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html) is a [`ufunc`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html) and use its `where` [keyword](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#ufuncs-kwargs):

```
result = arr.copy()
np.sqrt(arr, where=mask, out=result)
```

One popular way to apply the mask would be to use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) but I specifically constructed this example to show the caveats. The simplistic approach would be to compute

```
result = np.where(mask, np.sqrt(arr), arr)
```

`where` chooses the value from either `np.sqrt(arr)` or `arr` depending on whether `mask` is truthy or not. This is a very good method in many cases, but you have to have the values pre-computed for both branches, which is exactly what to want to avoid with a square root.

**TL;DR**

Your specific example is looking for a representation of the mask itself. If you don't care about the type:

```
result = arr >= 0
```

If you do care about the type:

```
result = (arr >= 0).astype(int)
```

OR

```
result = -np.clip(arr, -1, 0)
```

These solutions create a different array from the input. If you want to replace values in the same buffer,

```
mask = arr >= 0
arr[mask] = 1
arr[~mask] = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([-2,-1,0,1,2])

a[a>=0]=1
a[a<0]=0

>>> a
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the above solutions could be combining list comprenhension with ternary operators.

```
my_array = np.array([-1.2, 3.0, -10.11, 5.2])
sol = np.asarray([0 if val < 0 else 1 for val in my_array])
```

take a look to these sources
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions
https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html

Answer (score -2):

Use numpy.vectorize():

```
import numpy as np

def unit(elem):
    if elem < 0:
        elem = 0
    else:
        elem = 1
a = np.array([[1, 2, -0.5], [0.5, 2, 3]])
vfunc = np.vectorize(unit)
vfunc(a)

# array([[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: this is slow...

Comment: I did. This is not a good place to use `vectorize`