# Implement Relu derivative in python numpy

Tags: machine-learning, python, derivative, numpy

I'm trying to implement a function that computes the Relu derivative for each element in a matrix, and then return the result in a matrix. I'm using Python and Numpy.

Based on other Cross Validation posts, the Relu derivative for x is
1 when x > 0, 0 when x < 0, undefined or 0 when x == 0

Currently, I have the following code so far:

```
def reluDerivative(self, x):
    return np.array([self.reluDerivativeSingleElement(xi) for xi in x])

def reluDerivativeSingleElement(self, xi):
    if xi > 0:
        return 1
    elif xi <= 0:
        return 0
```

Unfortunately, xi is an array because x is an matrix. reluDerivativeSingleElement function doesn't work on array. So I'm wondering is there a way to map values in a matrix to another matrix using numpy, like the exp function in numpy?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: [np.heaviside](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.heaviside.html)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
>>> def reluDerivative(x):
...     x[x<=0] = 0
...     x[x>0] = 1
...     return x

>>> z = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (3,3))
>>> z
array([[ 0.41287266, -0.73082379,  0.78215209],
       [ 0.76983443,  0.46052273,  0.4283139 ],
       [-0.18905708,  0.57197116,  0.53226954]])
>>> reluDerivative(z)
array([[ 1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Thanks, I made copy of x so that the original x is not modified.

Comment: @Bon, why do you think original x will be modified? I suppose, `x` is local variable for `reluDerivative` function, it shouldn't affect `x` outside that scope, isn't it?

Comment: @RishabhAgrahari `x` would be a numpy array that is passed by reference so modifying `x` within `reluDerivative` would modify the original `x` that is passed into the function

Comment: @Bon Thanks. But how do you know `x` is passed by reference, this doesn't happen generally, right?

Comment: Just want to note that this is technically just one of many programmatic solution since the derivative of ReLU is undefined at 0. So instead of `x[x<=0] = 0` other common implementations that work in practice are `x[x<0] = 0` & `x[x==0] = 1` and  `x[x<0] = 0` & `x[x==0] = 0.5`

Comment: def dRelu(z):
    return np.where(z <= 0, 0, 1)

Answer (score 28):

That's an exercise in vectorization.

This code

```
if x > 0:
  y = 1
elif xi <= 0:
  y = 0
```

Can be reformulated into

```
y = (x > 0) * 1
```

This is something that will work for numpy arrays, since boolean expressions involving them are turned into arrays of values of these expressions for elements in said array.

Comment: I put this code in my reluDerivativeSingleElement function. It still says it cannot work with array. Maybe I interpret your answer wrongly?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense - this code is supposed to work on whole array

Comment: Why not simply `y = (x > 0)*1.0`  Seems to produce the same results as `y = (x > 0) * 1 + (x <= 0) * 0`

Answer (score 19):

Basic function to return derivative of relu could be summarized as follows:

```
f'(x) = x > 0
```

So, with numpy that would be:

```
def relu_derivative(z):
    return np.greater(z, 0).astype(int)
```

Comment: This seems to be the fastest implementation provided in this thread.

Answer (score 10):

```
def dRelu(z):
    return np.where(z <= 0, 0, 1)
```

Here z is a ndarray in my case.

Answer (score 5):

```py
def reluDerivative(self, x): 
    return 1 * (x > 0)
```

Edit: OP had `self` in the function parameter as it was part of a `class`.

Comment: @OlivierD'Ancona Why? Then for ```x=0```, the function will return 1.

Comment: You're right because the derivative is not defined in x = 0 with lim x->0- we have 0 and with lim x->0+ we have 1. Therefore the derivative isn't continuous. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Neil in the comments, you can use [heaviside](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.heaviside.html) function of numpy.

```
def reluDerivative(self, x):
    return np.heaviside(x, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on a good track: thinking on vectorized operation. Where we define a function, and we apply this function to a matrix, instead of writing a for loop.

This threads answers your question, where it replace all the elements satisfy the condition. You can modify it into ReLU derivative.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766757/replacing-numpy-elements-if-condition-is-met

In addition, python supports functional programming very well, try to use lambda function.

https://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
def dReLU(x):
    return 1. * (x > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure Python:

```py
def relu_derivative(x):
    return max(sign(x), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it with the derivative you can use:

```
def relu(neta):
    relu = neta * (neta > 0)
    d_relu = (neta > 0)
    return relu, d_relu
```

Answer (score -1):

When x is larger than 0, the slope is 1. 
When x is smaller than or equal to 0, the slope is 0.

```
if (x > 0):
    return 1
if (x <= 0):
    return 0
```

This can be written more compact:

```
return 1 * (x > 0)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and although more compact is less readable.