# ReLU activation function outputs HUGE numbers

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, activation-function

I have FINALLY been able to implement backpropagation, but there are still some bugs I need to fix.  The main is issue the following: **My ReLU activation function produces really big dJdW values (derivative of error function wrt weights).**  When this gets subtracted from the weights, my output becomes a matrix of -int or inf.  How do I stop this?  As of now, the only solution I have is to make my learning rate *scalar* variable REALLY small.

```
 import numpy as np


class Neural_Network(object):
    def __init__(self, input_, hidden_, output_, numHiddenLayer_, numExamples_):
        # Define Hyperparameters
        self.inputLayerSize = input_
        self.outputLayerSize = output_
        self.hiddenLayerSize = hidden_
        self.numHiddenLayer = numHiddenLayer_
        self.numExamples = numExamples_
        self.learningRate = 0.000000001 # LEARNING RATE: Why does ReLU produce such large dJdW values?
        self.weightDecay = 0.5
        # in -> out
        self.weights = [] # stores matrices of each layer of weights
        self.z = [] # stores matrices of each layer of weighted sums
        self.a = [] # stores matrices of each layer of activity 
        self.biases = [] # stores all biases

        # Biases are matrices that are added to activity matrix
        # Dimensions -> numExamples_*hiddenLayerSize or numExamples_*outputLayerSize
        for i in range(self.numHiddenLayer):
            # Biases for hidden layer
            b = [np.random.random() for x in range(self.hiddenLayerSize)];
            B = [b for x in range(self.numExamples)];
            self.biases.append(np.mat(B))
        # Biases for output layer
        b = [np.random.random() for x in range(self.outputLayerSize)]
        B = [b for x in range(self.numExamples)];
        self.biases.append(np.mat(B))


        # Weights (Parameters)
        # Weight matrix between input and first layer
        W = np.random.rand(self.inputLayerSize, self.hiddenLayerSize)
        self.weights.append(W)

        for i in range(self.numHiddenLayer-1):
            # Weight matrices between hidden layers
            W = np.random.rand(self.hiddenLayerSize, self.hiddenLayerSize)
            self.weights.append(W)
        # Weight matric between hiddenlayer and outputlayer
        self.weights.append(np.random.rand(self.hiddenLayerSize, self.outputLayerSize))

    def setBatchSize(self, numExamples):
        # Changes the number of rows (examples) for biases
        if (self.numExamples > numExamples):
            self.biases = [b[:numExamples] for b in self.biases]

    def sigmoid(self, z):
        # Apply sigmoid activation function
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))

    def sigmoidPrime(self, z):
        # Derivative of sigmoid function
        return self.sigmoid(x)*(1-self.sigmoid(z))

    def ReLU(self, z):
        # Apply activation function
        '''
        for (i, j), item in np.ndenumerate(z):
            if (item < 0):
                item *= 0.01
            else:
                item = item
        return z'''
        return np.multiply((z < 0), z * 0.01)  + np.multiply((z >= 0), z)


    def ReLUPrime(self, z):
        # Derivative of ReLU activation function\
        '''
        for (i, j), item in np.ndenumerate(z):
            if (item < 0):
                item = 0.01
            else:
                item = 1
        return z'''
        return (z < 0) * 0.01 + (z >= 0) * 1

    def forward(self, X):
        # Propagate outputs through network
        self.z = []
        self.a = []
        self.z.append(np.dot(X, self.weights[0]) + self.biases[0])

        self.a.append(self.ReLU(self.z[0]))

        #viewZ = self.z
        #viewA = self.a

        for i in range(1, self.numHiddenLayer):
            self.z.append(np.dot(self.a[-1], self.weights[i]) + self.biases[i])
            self.a.append(self.ReLU(self.z[-1]))

        self.z.append(np.dot(self.z[-1], self.weights[-1]) + self.biases[-1])
        self.a.append(self.ReLU(self.z[-1]))
        yHat = self.ReLU(self.z[-1])
        return yHat

    def backProp(self, X, y):
        # Compute derivative wrt W
        # out -> in
        dJdW = [] # stores matrices of each dJdW (equal in size to self.weights[])
        delta = [] # stores matrices of each backpropagating error
        self.yHat = self.forward(X)

        # Quantifying Error
        J = np.multiply((y-self.yHat),(y-self.yHat)) * 0.5
        Javrg = np.dot(J.T, np.mat([1 for x in range(self.numExamples)]).reshape(self.numExamples, 1))
        print(Javrg.item(0))

        delta.insert(0,np.multiply(-(y-self.yHat), self.ReLUPrime(self.z[-1]))) # delta = (y-yHat)(sigmoidPrime(final layer unactivated))
        dJdW.insert(0, np.dot(self.a[-2].T, delta[0]) + (self.weightDecay*self.weights[-1])) # dJdW

        for i in range(len(self.weights)-1, 1, -1):
            # Iterate from self.weights[-1] -> self.weights[1]
            delta.insert(0, np.multiply(np.dot(delta[0], self.weights[i].T), self.ReLUPrime(self.z[i-1])))
            dJdW.insert(0, np.dot(self.a[i-2].T, delta[0]) + (self.weightDecay*self.weights[i-1]))

        delta.insert(0, np.multiply(np.dot(delta[0], self.weights[1].T), self.ReLUPrime(self.z[0])))
        dJdW.insert(0, np.dot(X.T, delta[0]) + (self.weightDecay*self.weights[0]))


        return dJdW

    def train(self, X, y):
        for t in range(60000):
            dJdW = self.backProp(X, y)
            for i in range(len(dJdW)):
                self.weights[i] -= self.learningRate*dJdW[i]

# Instantiating Neural Network
inputs = [int(np.random.randint(0,1000)) for x in range(1000)]
x = np.mat([x for x in inputs]).reshape(1000,1)
y = np.mat([x+1 for x in inputs]).reshape(1000,1)
NN = Neural_Network(1,3,1,1,1000)


# Training
print("INPUT: ", end = '\n')
print(x, end = '\n\n')

print("BEFORE TRAINING", NN.forward(x), sep = '\n', end = '\n\n')
print("ERROR: ")
NN.train(x,y)
print("\nAFTER TRAINING", NN.forward(x), sep = '\n', end = '\n\n')

# Testing
test = np.mat([int(np.random.randint(0,10080)) for x in range(1000)]).reshape(1000,1)
print("TEST INPUT:", test, sep = '\n', end = '\n\n')
print(NN.forward(test), end = '\n\n')


NN.setBatchSize(1) # changing settings to receive one input at a time

while True:
    # Give numbers between 0-100 (I need to fix overfitting) and it will get next value
    inputs = input()
    x = np.mat([int(i) for i in inputs.split(" ")])
    print(NN.forward(x))
```

I first made the ANN using sigmoid but Leaky ReLU is faster.
The code is a bit much so here is a summary:

1. Neural Network Class

   - define hyperparameter and stuff (include really small learning rate scalar)
   - activation functions and their derivatives (*ReLU* and sigmoid)
   - Member functions: forward propagation, backpropagation, setBatchSize etc.
2. Instantiating ANN

   - setting hyperparameters (topology of ANN)
   - creating data (one array has values x and the output array has values x+1)
3. Training

   - using inputs generated in step 2 to train ANN
4. Testing

   - Testing using randomly generated inputs
   - User can give inputs

Hope that helps you help me.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you fit on normalized data? BTW your sigmoid derivative is wrong, you need to multiply it by sigmoid (s'(x) = s(x) (1 - s(x))

Comment: Jakub Bartczuk I'm training my NN to count so I don't know if I could even normalise that.

Comment: BTW you can also try to add weight decay. This can help because it explicitly penalizes big weights

Comment: Also, did you check what happens when you run smaller number of iterations? Mabe it doesn't blow up in 100 steps?

Comment: Will it learn on 100 steps?

Comment: I just ran scikit-learn's MLPRegressor on this data. It doesn't blow up, but it doesn't learn anything useful either. I think a wise idea is to try to compare your implementation with something that does work.

Answer (score 0):

Your ReLU and ReLUPrime are wrong. When you iterate over a collection and mutate items it doesn't change the collection. Also: try to not explicitly iterate over arrays in numpy, but use vectorized operations, because they are way faster. It should be a good exercise to rewrite ReLU and its derivative in vectorized form. If you aren't sure what I mean, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411180/implement-relu-derivative-in-python-numpy/46411340#46411340).

Apart from that sigmoidPrime is wrong, it should be

```
self.sigmoid(z) * (1-self.sigmoid(z))
```

PS
This problem isn't really well suited for neural network, at least not for this encoding - I've tried it with exact hyperparameters with scikit-learn MLPRegressor and its output doesn't make much sense.

Comment: i've done your suggestions,  It works a lot better no BUT it still outputs huge numbers