# How to replace values in a numpy array based on 2 other columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let say I have the following array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(10, size=(3,5))

print(a)
```

Output looks like below:

[[4 0 3 7 3]
[6 5 7 3 3]
[6 6 4 2 1]]

If I want to select the row where column 0 element is 4 and replace column 2 element with 6, I can do the following.

`a[a[:, 0] == 4, 2] = 6`

Output will be as below:

[[4 0 6 7 3]
[6 5 7 3 3]
[6 6 4 2 1]]

How can I select the row where column 0 element is 6 **AND** column 1 element is 5 and replace column 2 element with 9 so that the output is as below:

[[4 0 6 7 3]
[6 5 9 3 3]
[6 6 4 2 1]]

Comment: Related:[Replacing elements in a numpy array when there are multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135539/replacing-elements-in-a-numpy-array-when-there-are-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a bitwise AND on the conditions:

```
a[(a[:, 0] == 6) & (a[:, 1] == 5), 2] = 9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the array row-wise with a tuple/list and use `all`:

```
a[(a[:,:2]==(6,5)).all(axis=1), 2] = 9
```