# How to replace value of numpy array for multiple condition in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with some random values and nan .I want to replace the value 1,3,7 with 100 and all others element will remain same.
The original array is:

```
 [[nan, 2, 5, ..., 1,nan,5],
  [7, nan, 8, ..., 5, 2, 6],
  [1, 9, 7, ..., 2, nan, 8],
   ...,
  [3,nan,nan, ..., 1,7,nan],
  [nan,2,nan, ..., 6, 5, 8],
  [7,nan,nan, ...,nan,1, 3]]
```

My expected output is:

```
 [[nan, 2, 5, ..., 100, nan, 5],
  [100, nan, 8, ...,  5,  2, 6],
  [100, 9,100, ..., 2, nan,  8],
   ...,
  [100,nan,nan,..., 1, 100,nan],
  [nan,2,nan, ...,  6,   5,  8],
  [100,nan,nan,...,nan,100,100]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing elements in a numpy array when there are multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135539/replacing-elements-in-a-numpy-array-when-there-are-multiple-conditions)

Comment: Something like this? `mask = np.isin(arr, [1, 3, 7])` then replace with `arr[mask] = 100`

Comment: the np.isin  method is working fine.Thanks @ Milos Stojanovic

Comment: if you will have more conditions then you can always create many masks - `mask1 = ...`, `mask2 = ...`, etc.  and late run `arr[ mask1 & mask2 & ... ]` (or maybe `arr[ mask1 and mask2 and ... ]`) and `arr[ mask1 | mask2 | ... ]` (or maybe `arr[ mask1 or mask2 or ... ]`