# Python, Numpy, replace certain values in an image

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for an efficient way to replace certain values within a numpy image.
So far this is where I got :

```
def observation(self, img):
    # 45 50 184
    background = np.array([45, 50, 184])
    # 80 0 132
    border = np.array([80, 0, 132])
    img = self.crop(img)
    for line_index, line in enumerate(img):
        for pixel_index, pixel in enumerate(line):
            if not np.array_equal(pixel, background) and not np.array_equal(pixel, border):
                img[line_index][pixel_index] = [254, 254, 254]
```

The idea is to replace all the colors that are not background or border to white.
I'm quite new to this, so I'm fairly sure that there is a more efficient way to do this.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.where` should do the job. You have to call it twice (one for the background and one for the border) or combine the 2 conditions `img != background` and `img != border`:

```
np.where(np.logical_and(img!=background, img != border), img, [254, 254, 254])
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766757/replacing-numpy-elements-if-condition-is-met) for a small example (possible duplicate?)

Hope it helps

Comment: It does the job, I had to change the order between img and the white color array, but it is indeed more efficient performance wise.

Comment: Good news! I wrote and tested quickly, I did not notice the inversion of the two arrays, sorry.