# Numpy replacing elements based on logic and value in an identically shaped array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, if-statement, logical-operators

I have 2 numpy arrays. One is filled with boolean values and the other numerical values.

How would I perform logic on the numerical array based on also the current value in the boolean array.

e.g. if true and > 5 then make the value false

```
matrix1
matrix2

newMatrix = matrix1 > 5 where matrix2 value is false
```

Please note that these arrays have the same shape e.g.

```
[[0, 1, 1],  
[1, 0, 0]]
```

and

```
[[3, 1, 0]  
[6, 2, 6]]
```

And the result I would like would be a new boolean matrix that is true if its value is true in the boolean array and the equivalent value in the numerical array is more than 5 e.g.

```
[[0, 0, 0]  
[1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Please, provide an example of the data you work with and the result you want to achieve.

Comment: @sentence updated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343752/numpy-where-function-multiple-conditions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528328/numpy-logical-or-for-more-than-two-arguments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766757/replacing-numpy-elements-if-condition-is-met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newMatrix = np.logical_and(matrix2 == 0, matrix1 > 5 )
```

This will iterate over all elements, and make an 'and' between pairs of booleans from `matrix == 0` and `matrix1 > 5`. Note that `matrix1 > 5` type of expression generates a matrix of boolean values.

If you want 0,1 instead of False,True, you can add +0 to the result:

```
newMatrix = np.logical_and(matrix2 == 0, matrix1 > 5 ) + 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The **clearest** way:

```
import numpy as np

matrix1 = np.array([[3, 1, 0],
                    [6, 2, 6]])

matrix2 = np.array([[0, 1, 1],
                    [1, 0, 0]])

r,c = matrix1.shape

res = np.zeros((r,c))

for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        if matrix1[i,j]>5 and matrix2[i,j]==1:
            res[i,j]=1
```

**result**

```
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.]])
```

---

A **fancier** way, using [`numpy.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

matrix1 = np.array([[3, 1, 0],
                    [6, 2, 6]])

matrix2 = np.array([[0, 1, 1],
                    [1, 0, 0]])

r,c = matrix1.shape

res = np.zeros((r,c))

res[np.where((matrix1>5) & (matrix2==1))]=1
```

**result**

```
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.]])
```