# modify a numerical array or an image based on the given threshold

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

I have an image, and would like to modify the image based on a given threshold. The function such as

```
binary = image > threshold
```

will create a binary image. What I want is the image pixels will remain the same if it is higher than the threshold. Are there any convenient function to do that?

Comment: .. `numpy.clip`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing Numpy elements if condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766757/replacing-numpy-elements-if-condition-is-met)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
image[image < threshold] = 0
```

will clip every pixel below the threshold to 0 and will leave the rest intact