# Problem with replacing values in a numpy.array with a for-loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, random

I'm doing stastitics on cointossing. I need a N number of values to be either 0 or 1 based on random numbers.

My code:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(10)

for i in x:
    if i < 0.5:
        i ==  0
    elif i >= 0.5:
        i == 1

print(x)
```

The code still returns a vector of 10 random numbers between 0 and 1. How can i change my code so it returns a vector of N number of 0 and 1 based on the random vector?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing Numpy elements if condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766757/replacing-numpy-elements-if-condition-is-met)

Comment: In a Python loop, changing the iteration variable (here `i`) does not change values in the source (`x`).  That's true whether `x` is a list or array.   (Unless `i` is a mutable object).  Also with a numpy arrays it's usually more efficient to avoid a loop entirely.