# How to set very small numbers to zero in numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

What is the best way to set numbers smaller than a specified tolerance to zero in a real numpy array? In particular, my array has 3 dimensions.

```py
import numpy as np

N = 25
D = 50
tolerance = 10**-2

X = np.random.normal(0, 1, (N, D, 4))
```

I would like to set to 0 all values of X smaller than the tolerance set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing Numpy elements if condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766757/replacing-numpy-elements-if-condition-is-met)

Comment: Small in amplitude, right? Because e.g. -100 is smaller than 10**-2, but you don't want to set it to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
X[X < tolerance] = 0
```

Comment: -10 would meet that condition

Comment: It shouldn't? why tho?

Comment: A normal distribution is symmetrical about zero

Comment: But how is my answer incorrect against the OP's question?

Comment: Just use `X[abs(X) < tolerance] = 0`.

Comment: whether the abs() is needed or not really depends on what you read, the question's header or text... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I think a better way would be to use `np.isclose`

```
X[np.isclose(X, 0, atol=tolerance)] = 0
```