# How to replace different values in each column with NAN values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Please let me know if anyone knows of a better way to do about the following.
I am trying to replace some values in numpy array.
Replace condition is differ in each columns.
Suppose I have a numpy array and list of nodata values like:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([[ 1, 2, 3],
                  [ 4, 5, 6],
                  [ 7, 8, 9],
                  [10,11,12]])
nodata_values = [4, 8, 3]
```

and what I want to have is array which values are replaced like

```
array([[ 1.,  2., nan],
       [nan,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7., nan,  9.],
       [10., 11., 12.]])
```

I know I can do this:

```
np.array([np.where(i == nodata_values[idx], np.nan, i) 
          for idx, i in enumerate(array.T)]).T
```

But this code using for loop inside therefore applying it to a table with **tens of thousands of rows** will takes time.

Comment: `nan` is a floating-point value, so your array can only contain it if the `dtype` is a floating-point type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing Numpy elements if condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766757/replacing-numpy-elements-if-condition-is-met)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, thanks your comment, I know that and I don't mind float format. because I want to have np.nan value.

Comment: `mask = (array==4) || (array == 8) || (array == 3); array[mask] = np.nan`

Comment: @jakub, I want different values for each column for a replacement condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) to create boolean index & broadcast.

[`astype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) to avoid `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

```
import numpy as np

array = array.astype(np.float)

array[np.isin(array , nodata_values)] = np.NaN
```

---

```
[[ 1.  2. nan]
 [nan  5.  6.]
 [ 7. nan  9.]
 [10. 11. 12.]]
```