# Ensure that an array has all values encoded as 1 and -1, not 1 and 0

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

There is a 1 dimensional `numpy` array named `"target_y"`. My task is to ensure that `"target_y"` has all values encoded as `1` and `-1`, not `1` and `0` before performing logistic regression. Once I do it, I need to assign it to `"prepared_y"` and return it. Can I write something like:

```
if target_y in 1,-1:
    prepared_y = target_y
```

Comment: Why not replace the `0` values with `-1`? A quick search for replacing values in an numpy array will show how this can be done.

Comment: Are you searching for [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)? Both `1` and `-1` will be interpreted as `True`, so `all(target_y)` will return `True` if there's no `0` items.

Comment: Is the goal to convert all 0's to -1's, or to return a boolean stating whether the array is valid or not?

Comment: Also, is it a `List` or a `numpy array`?

Comment: yes, the goal is to check if there are any 0's and convert them to -1's.

Comment: you're right! It's an array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing Numpy elements if condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766757/replacing-numpy-elements-if-condition-is-met)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace all `0` values with `-1` in a  `numpy.array` it’s as simple as:

```
a[a == 0] = -1
```

... where `a` is the 1 dimensional array.

Comment: Thank you! This is the easiest solution to my question.

Comment: My pleasure.  Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [`np.all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

We can do some quick boolean arithmetic to check if all the values are `1` or `-1`:

```py
if np.all((target_y == 1) + (target_y == -1)): # checks if the array has all 1s and -1s
    prepared_y = target_y
```

If you want to change all `0`s to `-1`s, slice for all `0`s:

```py
target_y[np.argwhere(target_y == 0)] = -1
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use `np.all(target_y)`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Not *quite*, but close. `np.all(arr)` will be true for all non-zero arrays. It does not check to see if it is all -1 and 1

Comment: Yes, I know, but it fits as a solution for this particular problem

Answer (score 0):

For a List you can do:

```py
def convert( l ):
  return [ -1 if e == 0 else e for e in l ]
```

For a `numpy array`

```py
def convert( l ):
  return l[ l == 0 ] = -1
```

Comment: `[e or -1 for e in l]`

Comment: The reason I did it this way is in case there are other values than just `1` and `0`, but indeed, if you can ensure that those are the only two values @OlvinRoght's suggestion will work, defaulting to -1 if e evaluates to False.

Answer (score 0):

One value can be checked by if statement, such as:

```py
if 0 in test_list:
    return test_list
```

To be exact to your answer, you need a loop to check each value:

```py
def list_checker(test_list):
    for i, num in enumerate(test_list):
        if num == 0:
            test_list[i] = -1
    return test_list
```